# Why is this simple python program not working the way I want it to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code snippet is meant to allow the user to input the answer to a question. They are allowed to enter four
answers: either `y` or `Y` for “yes”, or `n` or `N` for “no”. The program is supposed to print out the received answer if the
entry is valid, and print out an error message otherwise.

```
answer = input("What is your answer? ")
if answer == "y" or "Y":
    print("You answered yes")
elif answer == "n" or "N":
    print("You answered no")
else:
    print("You didn’t enter an acceptable answer")
```

It just keeps on saying that I answered `yes` regardless if I put `n` or `N` or some random thing. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 7):

The precedence of the `or` is not what you are expecting.  Instead try:

```
answer = input("What is your answer? ")
if answer in ("y", "Y"):
    print("You answered yes")
elif answer in ("n", "N"):
    print("You answered no")
else:
    print("You didn’t enter an acceptable answer")
```

Or maybe like:

```
answer = input("What is your answer? ")
if answer.lower() == "y":
    print("You answered yes")
elif answer.lower() == "n":
    print("You answered no")
else:
    print("You didn’t enter an acceptable answer")
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first condition will always return true because `"Y"` is always truthy.

Try: `if answer == "y" or answer == "Y":`

And the same modification for the other conditional.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a variable shortly as you want, use something like this:

```
if answer in ["y","Y"]:
```

It will return True if `answer` is `y` or `Y`